# Как заблокировать нажатие кнопки на JS?

Tags: javascript

Задача: если не заполнено одно - не дать отправить форму.
Варианта 2:

1) не дать нажать

2) дать нажать, но показать сообщение что данные заполнены некорректно и тут надо как-то отменить нажатие иначе форма всё же уйдёт на сервер

В первом случае надо ловить наведение курсора на кнопку, менять курсор, type submit и выводить сообщение?

Во втором случае вопрос как отменить отправку?

Comment: Для всего этого не нужен js. Есть 1. https://webref.ru/html/input/required 2. https://webref.ru/html/input/pattern 3. https://webref.ru/html/input/placeholder 4. https://webref.ru/html/input/type

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/LLf9xqmx/

Comment: @Visman спасибо, про это всё зднаю, этот input имеет тип hidden поэтому юзер просто не поймёт что от него хотят при использовании того на что вы ссылаетесь, требуется более явно, более выразительно

Comment: @soledar10 агонь конечно, такая штука заслуживает плюса, хоть и не уведомляет пользователя что конкретно неправильно если полей несколько

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы кнопка была заблокирована, можно просто использовать свойство disabled у элемента:

```
document.getElementById("MyButton").disabled = true;
```

А чтобы заблокировать отправку на сервер можно сделать в обработчике отправки проверку наличия текста в поле:

```
var input = document.getElementById("MyInput");
if (input && input.value) {
    //выполнить отправку
}
else{
    //показать сообщение (множество вариантов)
     alert('Ошибка при отправке данных, заполните поле');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вешаем на onsubmit обработчик и если что-то не так возвращаем в нем false

```
<form onsubmit="return onSubmit()">
    <input id="etopolenadoproverit" type="text">
    <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
<script>
    function onSubmit(){
       if (!etopolenadoproverit.value) {
           etopolenadoproverit.focus();
           alert('Вы не заполнили поле etopolenadoproverit');
           return false;
       }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Только смешивать HTML и JS плохая идея `onsubmit="return onSubmit()"` надо выносить в JS и ловить форму по Id например